# Spring Cloud QueueMessagingTemplate#convertAndSend Batch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to send a batch of items to Amazon SQS using Spring Cloud. I'm able to send individual items. However, the time to send it to the queue tends to be multiplied by the number of items I'm sending. I'm basically following the example of the [reference doc](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/aws-refapp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/sample/sqs/SqsController.java#L60)

In the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html) you can send a batch of up to 10 items at one time. So my question is does the QueueMessagingTemplate or another Spring Cloud class allow you to do this?

This code snippet shows what I want to do. I don't want to send the items as an object because I want each item placed separately on the queue.

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SqsConfigMappingProperties.class)
public class SqsServiceImpl implements SqsService {

    @Autowired
    String queueName;

    @Autowired
    QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;

    @Override
    public void sendSqsMessage(List items) {
        //Can't really send a batch size here
        int batchSize = 10;
        queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, items, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to achieve this? Even i am looking for something like this.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to do this using the QueueMessagingTemplate. You are able to do it using the AWS SQS libraries directly. We ended up doing something else to solve our performance issues.

Comment: Oh okay. But how do you use aws methods using spring boot, I found no other way other than this?

Comment: You're just going to use the AWS Java SDK 
here: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/
Then checkout this API
here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/SendMessageBatchRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

[There is no dedicated](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/2.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/core/support/AbstractMessageChannelMessagingSendingTemplate.html) `convertAndSend()` method or anything like that in the `QueueMessagingTemplate`. In fact these `QueueMessagingTemplate` does not define these method, it just inherts them. I would use something like a wrapper class for a collection to send it as a geenric `payload` in `convertAndSend()`.

***But there is more to it.***

`QueueMessagingTemplate`'s source code [is located in this repo](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-aws). This repo is archived (in favor of [this new repo](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws)) and is no longer maintained. In a new repo `QueueMessagingTemplate` is removed in favor of [SqsTemplate](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-aws-sqs/src/main/java/io/awspring/cloud/sqs/operations/SqsTemplate.java), and in `SqsTemplate` there is a `sendManyAsync()` method for instance that allows sending a batch of messages.

So it is really better for developers to migrate to a new library becuase `QueueMessagingTemplate` is no longer maintained (and even exist), and `SqsTemplate` has exactly what you want.

Hope it helped, have a nice day :)